# Python получение всех ключей из документа Word

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, docxtpl

Вопрос следующий.
Библиотека docxtpl позволяет вместо ключей в Word по типу {{text}} вставлять свои значения.
Можно ли как то с помощью данной библиотеки получить все такие ключи?
Логика состоит в следующем:
Пользователь сам в документе размещает эти ключи и называет их как хочет, а программа уже должна понять, какие именно там есть ключи и предложить заполнить их.

Тут вопрос именно в том, можно ли это сделать с помощью библиотеки docxtpl, а не используя сторонние методы, например регулярные выражения.

Comment: Посмотрев, какие функции есть у этой библиотеки, вы сможете самостоятельно ответить на свой вопрос.